# Being born religious argument

Tags: atheism

How do you answer the argument by atheists that you are religious because you have been born and raised as a religious person and you believe in the stuff religion has told you because it has been embedded as such a major part of your life. If you were born atheist and then looked at religion you most likely wouldn’t convert to religion. Your culture and surroundings are the result of your religion and not your understanding and knowledge itself.

I find this to be true pretty much everywhere where I live and even within my own family. And taking into consideration the fact that conversion from religion to atheism is a lot lot higher than the amount of conversion from atheism to religion it seems that culture really may have an impact on religious background and when they gain an understanding/knowledge people tend to leave.

Comment: I wonder if these kinds of questions are on-topic. As it sounds like a defend yourself question.

Comment: Can be very helpful though also if anyone still has answers please post them here

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to argue against it because it isn't a real argument. It doesn't make any statement either about Islam or atheism.

Two responses to this can be that:

- The same thing applies in reverse. Atheists are so careless of religion because either they were raised in an atheist household or a household where religion wasn't emphasized. So, this "argument" does not support their world view either. For the exceptional atheists who were raised in religious households, we have exceptional Muslim converts as well.
- Both apostates from Islam and converts to Islam show that even though your birth may have influence, you have your own choice. You can choose what you want to be.
- It is definitely not true that when Muslims get knowledge they tend to leave. There is very little evidence of that. For most people, more knowledge raises their faith.

And eventually, it is better to bring the discussion back to the truth value of Islam vs atheism. The actions of people are really not of concern in that discussion.

The entire world can be atheist, and Islam would still be true. If Islam was false, even if every person who heard of Islam accepted it, it would still be false. The acceptance rate of something doesn't make a difference to whether it is true.

Comment: I mean knowledge of science etc. Also there are significantly more concerts from religion to atheism than from atheism to religion which also suggests this. Most of Islam’s population live in underdeveloped places whereas in the flourishing and advancing places such as UK or USA atheism is on the rise and this isn’t necessarily due to birth rates but more from conversions and we can see this as atheists typically have lower birth rates than all religions. It seems that Islam is flourishing because lots of Muslims are being born not necessarily due to conversions or acquiring knowledge.

Comment: @ExcogitatingThing As I said for most people, knowledge increases faith. There is no evidence of there being more converts to either side. And even if there was, it is a non-argument. It makes no difference whether there are more converts to one thing or another. Atheism is on the rise in UK and USA because Christianity doesn't make sense. Islam has nothing to do with that.

Comment: But that still doesn’t necessarily answer the question. Islam is increasing but not necessarily on the basis of knowledge but more or less because their families are Muslims however most atheists converts have Converter due to the knowledge they have acquired and most atheists live in well developed countries where they are taught and learn about God and hence why they come to the conclusions made however in Islam most people around are Muslim so it is just a generally accepted thing and a lot of Muslims live in underdeveloped places and don’t have lots of knowledge.

Comment: Also don’t you think if Christianity didn’t make sense but Islam did then they would’ve converted to Islam instead of atheism however the rates of atheism is increasing faster than Islam in these countries and atheists also have lower birth rates than Islam which shows that the increase of atheism is based more in conversions and acquiring knowledge rather than just frequent births as is happening in Islam?

Comment: @ExcogitatingThing Leaving religion is easier than researching other religions. That is the obvious reason most people become atheists from Christianity. In fact, as far as I know, a lot of converts to Islam are atheists or agnostics who have become disillusioned from Christianity, but unlike others who simply stayed atheist, researched into other religions to find the truth.

Comment: Ok but also atheists dominate the fields of science, philosophy and all these fields that require so much knowledge and study. Most atheists live in very developed places and it is clear that a significantly higher percentage of atheists are well educated compared to Islam for example where most Muslims live in underdeveloped countries and some don’t even have knowledge of their own religion. So by this it seems that a large amount of Muslims just blindly follow because it has been embedded in their lifestyle not necessarily based on knowledge.

Comment: @ExcogitatingThing Knowledge is different from just scientific knowledge. Even the insight of a simple farmer observing the world and coming to the realization of God is better knowledge than knowledge that is only used for the world. Knowing exactly how Quantum physics works for instance gives no more or less insight into God except to show how amazing Allah's creation is. The same amazement can be had from other things. You do not need to learn Quantum physics to be amazed of Allah's creation.